# trying to mirror one storage drive of size 2n to two storage drives of 1n each

Tags: backup, nas, rsync, storage, mirroring

use case:

I have two hard disk drives of 2tb each. Currently I am mirroring one to the other. The disks however are almost full.

I am now planning to get a 4tb hard drive and use that as the original am wondering if i can split the mirror somehow between the two old 2tb drives without specifying the directories manually. I am wondering if rsync has something like an overflow mode.

i am on debian. i cannot afford to buy additional hardware, so I can't just buy two 4tb drives. eventually i do plan on getting a jbod enclosure and going with a zfs pool maybe. will plan the software side of that when the time comes.

Comment: You can span a single volume across multiple disks at the OS level (steps depend on windows/linux/mac). That works well enough for file-level mirroring like with rsync

Comment: What's your OS?

Comment: @harrymc im on debian.

Comment: LVM seems to be a solution but it doesnt appear to be portable. I would like the disks to work on any box i connect them to. With LVM, my understanding is that they will work only on the box i configure them in?